# primefaces autocomplete javax.servlet.ServletException

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

JSF / PF 3.5 / Hibernate

A Help on this please. Im getting error *when submitting form only for saving*

***javax.servlet.ServletException: NaturezaOperacao cannot be cast to java.lang.String***

```
<p:autoComplete id="txtCFOP" minQueryLength="2"
    value="#{NatOpMB.naturezaOperacao}"
    completeMethod="#{NatOpMB.autoCompleteQuery}" var="natop"
    required="true" converter="autoCompleteConverter"
    itemValue="#{natop}" 
    itemLabel="#{natop.descfopDE}">

<p:column>  
    #{natop.descfopDE}  
</p:column>  

<p:column width="250">  
    #{natop.desdescricao} 
</p:column> 

</p:autoComplete>
```

**BEAN :**

```
private NaturezaOperacao naturezaOperacao;

public List<NaturezaOperacao> autoCompleteQuery(String query) {  
    List<NaturezaOperacao> results = new ArrayList<NaturezaOperacao>();
    results = naturezaOperacaoServico.buscar(NaturezaOperacao.SEARCHNAMEDQUERY);
    return results;  
}
```

**ENTITY :**

```
public class NaturezaOperacao{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4560310741558931229L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idt_cfop",unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="des_cfopDE", length=18,unique=false, nullable=true)
    private String descfopDE;

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id=id;     
    }

    public String getDescfopDE() {
        return descfopDE;
    }

    public void setDescfopDE(String descfopDE) {
        this.descfopDE = descfopDE;
    }
}
```

**CONVERTER :**

```
@FacesConverter(value="autoCompleteConverter")
public class autoCompleteConverter implements Converter {

private static List<NaturezaOperacao> entities = new ArrayList<NaturezaOperacao>();

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
        entities.add((NaturezaOperacao)arg2);
        return String.valueOf(((NaturezaOperacao) arg2).getDescfopDE());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String submittedValue) {

        if (submittedValue.trim().equals("")) {  
        return null;  
    } else {  
        try {  
        String number = submittedValue;  

        for (NaturezaOperacao p : entities) {  
            if(p.getDescfopDE() != null){
                    if (p.getDescfopDE().toString().equals(number.toString())) {  
                        return p;  
                    }  
            }
        }  

        } catch(NumberFormatException exception) { 
            System.out.println(exception.getCause());
        }  
    }  

    return null; 
    }

    public NaturezaOperacao getNatOp() {
        return natOp;
    }

    public void setNatOp(NaturezaOperacao natOp) {
        this.natOp = natOp;
    }
}
```

**FULL STACK ERROR :**

```
08:01:07,081 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (ajp-localhost-127.0.0.1-8009-4) br.com.xyz.sisxyz.entidade.NaturezaOperacao cannot be cast to java.lang.String: java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.xyz.sisxyz.entidade.NaturezaOperacao cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.validate(RegexValidator.java:160) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1149) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:967) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processValidators(Panel.java:297) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at br.com.xyz.filtro.FiltroEncode.doFilter(FiltroEncode.java:26) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:490) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:480) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2033) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

08:01:07,104 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sisxyz].[Faces Servlet]] (ajp-localhost-127.0.0.1-8009-4) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.xyz.sisxyz.entidade.NaturezaOperacao cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at javax.faces.validator.RegexValidator.validate(RegexValidator.java:160) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1149) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:967) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel.processValidators(Panel.java:297) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at br.com.xyz.filtro.FiltroEncode.doFilter(FiltroEncode.java:26) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:490) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:480) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2033) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. changed autocomplete value to value="#{NatOpMB.cfop}" and it worked together the converter. cfop is from NaturezaOperacao type. the error is I was trying to use the same main entity (naturezaOperacao) in the autocomplete and for saving the record either.